# Pass a closure as an argument and store it to be called later

Tags: rust, object-lifetime

I have code similar to the following:

```
pub struct Delay {
    // This line would also need to change, obviously
    handle: Option<&'static Fn()>,
}

impl Delay {
    pub fn new() -> Delay {
        Delay { handle: None }
    }

    pub fn do_later<H>(&mut self, handle: H)
    where
        H: Fn(),
    {
        // This line is the problem child. Of all the things I've tried
        // none of them work. Including...
        self.handle = Some(handle);
        self.handle = Some(&handle);
        self.handle = Some(&'static handle);
    }

    pub fn do_now(&self) {
        match self.handle {
            Some(handle) => handle(),
            None => (),
        };
    }
}

pub struct Action;

impl Action {
    pub fn new() -> Action {
        Action
    }

    pub fn link(&self, target: &mut Delay) {
        target.do_later(|| {
            println!("Doin' stuff!!");
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut delay = Delay::new();
    let action = Action::new();

    action.link(&mut delay);
    delay.do_now();
}
```

In reference to the `do_later` function that I'm having trouble with and the 3 ways I've tried to fix it...

`handle` has an unknown size at compile time. Okay, that's fine, we'll just do it by reference then.

`&handle` may not live long enough, blah blah blah lifetimes. Okay, also fine. We just need to specify that it won't ever be cleared from memory by declaring it as static.

`&'static handle` spits out this garbage...

```
error: expected `:`, found `handle`
  --> example.rs:13:42
   |
13 |             self.handle = Some(&'static handle);
   |                                         ^^^^^^ expected `:`
```

I have no idea what's going on. Shouldn't this be valid syntax? If not, what do I need to do differently?

Comment: In short, you need to store the closure in a `Box<Option<Fn()>>`.  Dynamically-sized types can't be stored on the stack and must be stored on the heap instead.

Comment: The last error message is indeed not particularly helpful.  When applying the `&` operator to create a borrow, you can't specify a lifetime.  Rust figures out how long the variable you borrow lives automatically.  Since the parser does not expect a lifetime in this location, `'static` is interpreted as a loop label instead.  Labels need to be followed by a colon, which is why the parser throws this particular error message.

Comment: I'd [suggest an `Option<Box<...>` instead](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=ec771fbd9a5e15faa242663f8377e81a).